# How do I get Into the Bone Gallery?

Tags: torchlight-2

This quest says something about convincing the spirits to open the gate for me, but there are no spirits to be seen anywhere nearby.  How do I get in to the Bone Gallery?

[image: Rouse the Estherian Spirits?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Skull Hollow, by the 'A Shady Character' NPC (he gives you this quest) there should be two posts/pillars that you can smash. Smashing them will each release a ghost.

When you have gotten taken care of both ghosts, the gate to the Bone Gallery will open.